# Getting TypeError: this is undefined on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox, components

So, I am trying to create a checkbox component but I am having an issue.
My CheckedBox.js is this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function CheckedBox() {

return(
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      />
      </label>
)

}

export default CheckedBox;
```

And this is the part I am calling CheckedBox:

```
<CheckedBox checked={checked} handleChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}/> MyCheckBox
```

I am getting the error TypeError: this is undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: function dont't have key `this`

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: And where is the `this`? Check the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you are using function Component and pass props to it. So you can update like this:

```
function CheckedBox({checked, handleChange}) {
  return (
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={checked}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </label>
  );
}
```

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a functional component. Functional component don't have internal state in them like Class Components do. You need to use React Hooks to store state in functional components. Read more here: [Hooks intro](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), [API Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

In this case it would be better if you pass in props as value to make it a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```
import React from 'react';

function CheckedBox({value, onChange}) {

return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      </label>
   )
}

export default CheckedBox;
```

Comment: @Caeculus - Please select an answer.